# JavaScript - Assess logic within filter using checkbox state

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that is being filtered based on selected checkbox. The 'checked' boxes will indicate what objects are included in the output array. I have a fairly clunky way to do this now, but wondering if there is a more flexible method?

The `.filter()` method is currently hardcoded, but the actual web page has far more checkboxes and my approach is difficult to scale. I would like to include whatever variables are "checked".

```js
const updateBtn = document.getElementById("update-btn");
const fullData = [{
    "var1": "A",
    "var2": "C"
  },
  {
    "var1": "B",
    "var2": "C"
  },
  {
    "var1": "A",
    "var2": "D"
  },
  {
    "var1": "B",
    "var2": "D"
  }
];
let newData;
let checkboxState = [true, true, true, true];


updateBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const checkboxNames = ['checkTest1-A', 'checkTest2-B', 'checkTest8-C', 'checkTest7-D'];
  checkboxState = [];
  checkboxNames.forEach((el => {
    checkboxState.push(document.getElementById(el).checked);
  }))
  console.log(checkboxState);
  newData = fullData.filter(x => (x.var1.includes('A') === checkboxState[0] || x.var1.includes('B') === checkboxState[1]) && (x.var2.includes('C') === checkboxState[2] || x.var2.includes('D') === checkboxState[3]));
  console.log(newData);
})
```

```html
<h1>
  Var 1
</h1>
<input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkTest1-A" checked/>
<label for="checkTest1-A">Include A</label>
<input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkTest2-B" checked/>
<label for="checkTest2-B">Include B</label>
<h1>
  Var 2
</h1>
<input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkTest8-C" checked/>
<label for="checkTest8-C">Include C</label>
<input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkTest7-D" checked/>
<label for="checkTest7-D">Include D</label>

<h1>
  Update
</h1>
<button id="update-btn">
   Change Selections
   </button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the IDs of the checkboxes are the combination of the property name and value, you can use this in the filter. Concatenate the property name and value, then test that checkbox.

```js
//Unfiltered array of objects
const fullData = [{
    "var1": "A",
    "var2": "C"
  },
  {
    "var1": "B",
    "var2": "C"
  },
  {
    "var1": "A",
    "var2": "D"
  },
  {
    "var1": "B",
    "var2": "D"
  }
];

// Button that triggers filtering
const updateBtn = document.getElementById("update-btn");

//Default state of output data and checkboxes
let newData;
let checkboxState = [true, true, true, true];

updateBtn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  let newData = fullData.filter(x => Object.entries(x).some(([key, value]) =>
    document.getElementById(key + '-' + value).checked));
  console.log(newData);
})
```

```html
<h1>
  Var 1
</h1>
<input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="var1-A" checked/>
<label for="var1-A">Include A</label>
<input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="var1-B" checked/>
<label for="var1-B">Include B</label>
<h1>
  Var 2
</h1>
<input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="var2-C" checked/>
<label for="var2-C">Include C</label>
<input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="var2-D" checked/>
<label for="var2-D">Include D</label>

<h1>
  Update
</h1>
<button id="update-btn">
   Change Selections
</button>
```

Comment: Good catch on the pattern, but that was unintentional. The naming convention isn't the same. I'll edit the question to reflect this

Comment: If the IDs don't coincide like this, you can create another object that maps from these strings to the corresponding IDs. Or you can use `data-XXX` attributes.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly replicating the behaviour had with the question. When I select "Include A" and "include D" with my code I get one object: `var1: A` and `var2: D`. This code is including those with `var1: B` as it contains `D`

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted -- OR rather than AND. Change `some()` to `every()` to change that logic.

Answer (score 0):

first of all i rather using class name, then for what should check box do filter with, i use id of that check box(for A abd etc) and for whitch props filter should happen, you can add value like "var1", so somthing like  this:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".filter-checkbox").forEach(chb=>{
let prop = chb.value;
let v = chb.id.split("-")[1]:
fullData = fullData.filter(x=>x[prop].includes(v))
})
```

=== html added value to inputs:

```
<h1>
  Var 1
</h1>
<input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkTest1-A" value="var1" checked/>
<label for="checkTest1-A">Include A</label>
<input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkTest2-B" checked  value="var1"/>
<label for="checkTest2-B">Include B</label>
<h1>
  Var 2
</h1>
<input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkTest8-C" checked  value="var2"/>
<label for="checkTest8-C">Include C</label>
<input class="filter-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="checkTest7-D" checked  value="var2"/>
<label for="checkTest7-D">Include D</label>
```

so what is